# Read ascii grid data into matrix format

Tags: r, ascii, r-grid

I am trying to read a file in the ASCII TOMS grid format into R. I have been able to read it in such a way that it opens in R. However, iy opens as a linear matrix. A sumary of what the file contains is available here:

```
[Link](http://www.temis.nl/docs/README_TOMSASCII.pdf)
```

A sample of the data set could be downloaded here:

```
[Link](http://www.temis.nl/airpollution/no2col/no2monthscia.php?Year=2005&Month=04)
```

The data set is for January 2006 and I just renamed it for easy access as there are quite a few I need to work with. I read it in using:

```
CCC<-read.csv("no2_200601.asc",header=FALSE,skip=4,sep="\t")
dim(CCC)
[1] 52560    1
```

How do I read this into R so that data for each latitude is on a single row? I  feel this would help build a proper data structure.
Note: Let me try and simply it ias I understand:
 It means the structure is such that one line indicates the title e.g. lat=-89.9  and the next 144 lines with 20 elements each belong to row lat=-89.9; so my problem now is reading all these element before the next "lat=..." into one row.

In addition, I just tried to loop it through a set of files using this:

```
NO2files<-list.files(pattern=".asc", full.names=TRUE)
f<-lapply(NO2files, function (x) readLines (x))

for (i in 1:length (NO2files)) {  
 function(x)
 i<-readLines(x)
pattern <- "[[:digit:]]+(?=\\sbins)"
m <- regexpr(pattern, i[3], perl=TRUE)
dim <- regmatches(i[3], m)
m <- regexpr(pattern, i[4], perl=TRUE)
dim[2] <- regmatches(i[4], m)

dim <- as.integer(dim)

pattern <- "(?<=undef=).*"
m <- regexpr(pattern, i[2], perl=TRUE)
na_string <- regmatches(i[2], m)

dat1 <- i[-(1:4)]
sep <- grepl("=", dat1, fixed=TRUE)
dat2a <- dat1[sep] 
dat2b <- dat1[!sep] 
dat2b <- lapply(dat2b, substring, 
            first=seq(1,nchar(dat2b[1]),4), 
            last=  seq(4,nchar(dat2b[1]),4))
dat2b <- unlist(dat2b)
dat2b <- as.numeric(dat2b)
dat2b[dat2b==as.numeric(na_string)] <- NA
dat2b <- matrix(dat2b, nrow=dim[2], byrow=TRUE)
dat2b <- dat2b[nrow(dat2b):1, ]
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a nice file format. I wonder why people come up with something like this. However, I don't know any import functions that can parse this format (there might well be a package), so you'd need to write your own parser.

Comment: Not nice at all, From what I read, it means the structure is such that one line indicates the title e.g. lat=-89.9 and the next 144 lines with 20 elements each belong to row lat=-89.9; so my problem now is reading all these element before the next "lat=..." into one row.

Comment: I might have some time later this week to see if I can munge one of these programs : http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/ozone/additional/acdisc/additional/software-tools/ : to give you a way to pre-process your data prior to using in R. Not sure I'm up for building a package right now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not nearly as elegant as [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland)'s example and I'm not sure why  have different values - actually I do thx to the comment below (different file).

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(raster)

f <- readLines("totno2_200601.asc")

# how many lat/lon values
bins.lon <- as.numeric(str_match(f[3], "Longitudes *: *([0-9]+) bins")[2])
bins.lat <- as.numeric(str_match(f[4], "Latitudes *: *([0-9]+) bins")[2])

# number of characters that represent a value
num.width <- 4

# how many lines do we need to encode the longitude bins
bins.lon.lines <- as.integer(bins.lon / (80/num.width))

# where does the data start
curr.lat.line <- 5
curr.lat.bin <- 1

m <- matrix(nrow=bins.lat, ncol=bins.lon+1)

repeat {

  # get current latitude
  lat <- as.numeric(str_match(f[curr.lat.line], "lat=\ +([0-9\\.\\-]+)")[2])

  # show progress - not necessary
  cat(curr.lat.bin, lat); cat("\n")

  # get the values for the longitudes at current latitude
  vals <- paste(f[(curr.lat.line+1):(curr.lat.line+bins.lon.lines)], sep="", collapse="")

  # split them by 4 and assign to the proper entry
  m[curr.lat.bin, ] <- c(lat, as.numeric(laply(seq(1, nchar(vals), 4), function(i) substr(vals, i, i+3))))

  curr.lat.bin <- curr.lat.bin + 1
  curr.lat.line <- curr.lat.line + bins.lon.lines + 1

  if (curr.lat.bin > bins.lat) { break }

}

m <- m[nrow(m):1, ]

plot(raster(m))
```

[image: plot]

Since you added a requirement to have this be able to be used in a loop to read multiple files:

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(raster)

# this is the function-ized version 

tomsToMatrix <- function(fname, verbose=FALSE) {

  f <- readLines(fname)

  bins.lon <- as.numeric(str_match(f[3], "Longitudes *: *([0-9]+) bins")[2])
  bins.lat <- as.numeric(str_match(f[4], "Latitudes *: *([0-9]+) bins")[2])

  num.width <- 4
  bins.lon.lines <- as.integer(bins.lon / (80/num.width))
  curr.lat.line <- 5
  curr.lat.bin <- 1

  m <- matrix(nrow=bins.lat, ncol=bins.lon+1)

  repeat {
    lat <- as.numeric(str_match(f[curr.lat.line], "lat=\ +([0-9\\.\\-]+)")[2])
    if (verbose) { cat(curr.lat.bin, lat); cat("\n") }
    vals <- paste(f[(curr.lat.line+1):(curr.lat.line+bins.lon.lines)], sep="", collapse="")
    m[curr.lat.bin, ] <- c(lat, as.numeric(laply(seq(1, nchar(vals), 4), function(i) substr(vals, i, i+3))))
    curr.lat.bin <- curr.lat.bin + 1
    curr.lat.line <- curr.lat.line + bins.lon.lines + 1 
    if (curr.lat.bin > bins.lat) { break } 
  }

  m <- m[nrow(m):1, ]

  return(m)

}

setwd("/data/toms") # whatever the source directory is for **your** files

t.files <- list.files("/data/toms")
t.files
[1] "totno2_200504.asc" "totno2_200505.asc" "totno2_200506.asc"

dat <- lapply(t.files, tomsToMatrix)

str(dat)
List of 3
$ : num [1:720, 1:1441] 89.9 89.6 89.4 89.1 88.9 ...
$ : num [1:720, 1:1441] 89.9 89.6 89.4 89.1 88.9 ...
$ : num [1:720, 1:1441] 89.9 89.6 89.4 89.1 88.9 ...
```

If you need them as named entries, that should not be difficult to add.

Comment: You do not have the same values because it is not the same file :)

Comment: Doh! Totally did not look at the filename Roland used.

Comment: Hi hrbrmstr, I just tried writing this as a loop as I have to do this for many files.     NO2files<-list.files(pattern=".asc",       full.names=TRUE)
    datalist = lapply(NO2files, function(y)readLines(y)) 

    for (i in 1:length (datalist)) { 
......
W<-matrix(nrow=bins.lat, ncol=bins.lon+1) 
} . I get an error Error: String must be an atomic vector. How do I write this into a loop using the "for" statement or the lapply command, please? When i use lapply with the "matrix(nrow=bins.lat, ncol=bins.lon+1)" it says it is "non-numerical".

Comment: Sorry i was away for a while. I just did it and it worked great.I still have a problem, though. the values are negative. what could be the problem?

Comment: I hrbrmstr, I just multiplier all the tables by "-1" to get the positive values I hope that was logically "right".

Comment: all the values? There's a "-999" which indicates that no meaningful measurement has been available during the month (I think you knew that, tho :-)

Comment: Yes I did.  It totally matches the data in the other formats now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start:

```
dat <- readLines("totno2_200504.asc")

#parse dimensions
pattern <- "[[:digit:]]+(?=\\sbins)"
m <- regexpr(pattern, dat[3], perl=TRUE)
dim <- regmatches(dat[3], m)

m <- regexpr(pattern, dat[4], perl=TRUE)
dim[2] <- regmatches(dat[4], m)

dim <- as.integer(dim)

#parse NA string
pattern <- "(?<=undef=).*"
m <- regexpr(pattern, dat[2], perl=TRUE)
na_string <- regmatches(dat[2], m)

#parse data
dat1 <- dat[-(1:4)]
sep <- grepl("=", dat1, fixed=TRUE)
dat2a <- dat1[sep] #might be useful 
dat2b <- dat1[!sep] #the data
dat2b <- lapply(dat2b, substring, 
                first=seq(1,nchar(dat2b[1]),4), 
                last=  seq(4,nchar(dat2b[1]),4))
dat2b <- unlist(dat2b)
dat2b <- as.numeric(dat2b)
dat2b[dat2b==as.numeric(na_string)] <- NA
dat2b <- matrix(dat2b, nrow=dim[2], byrow=TRUE)
dat2b <- dat2b[nrow(dat2b):1, ] #flip in axis

library(raster)
plot(raster(dat2b))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys. both answers seem logical. i went for the second one because i am not soo technical with scripting in r yet.

Comment: HI Roland, I just tried looping  this method of extraction and it gave me an error "Error in matrix(dat2b, nrow = dim[2], byrow = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)" what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Since I can't see your code I can't say. Possibly the file format is different and the regex for finding the dimensions didn't work? Btw., if you want to use this in a loop, you should first wrap it in a function.

Comment: Hi @Roland,  I just edited my initial question to reflect my attempt at looping. I want to end up with a list of matrices or rasters I can subset.